# How do I solve this constrained linear programing (LP) problem with one free variable?

Tags: r, constraints, linear-programming, lpsolve, free-variable

I was researching methods to rank forecasts and found this paper, [A novel ranking procedure for forecasting approaches using Data Envelopment Analysis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040162516301482#bb0025), I've been working through the article and setting up my data, but I can't seem to replicate their LP formulation in R?

This is the formulation I'm referring to: [LP Formulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPWm8.png)

Here is an example I'm working through to try and replicate their results with the above formulation as a reference. The data is based off of 'Table 2. Log values of data of illustrative example' from the above mentioned article.

```
library(lpSolve)
library(nonparaeff)

DMU = c("FOR01", "FOR02", "FOR03", "FOR04", "FOR05")

log.data = matrix(data = as.numeric(c("1.794","1.575","3.576"
                                      ,"2.228","2.106","6.628"
                                      ,"2.399","1.871","6.354"
                                      ,"2.619","1.983","5.849"
                                      ,"2.559","1.541","5.676")), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

colnames(log.data) = c("M1", "M2", "M3")
rownames(log.data) = DMU

THETA = c(-1,-1,-1,0)

add.to.one = c(1,1,1,1,1) # Constraint so each lambda adds up to one.

f.obj = c(1)

f.con = cbind(THETA, rbind(t(log.data), add.to.one))

f.dir = c("<=","<=","<=","=")

f.rhs = c(1.794,1.575,3.576,1)

lp2(direction = "min", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs, free.var =  c(1))
```

I'm using the packages lpsolve and nonparaeff; nonparaeff extends the `lp()` function so it can handle free variables.

Using this code I end up getting the error:

> "Error: no feasible solution found".

However, in the article they end up with theta as 0 or 1 and the first lambda returning as 1. So I must be doing something wrong.

Did I apply the fourth constraint correctly ('add.to.one')? Also, `lp()` already assumes each variable to be >= to zero, but does it assume anything else?

Did I correctly translate the formulation to R? Am I using the `lp2` function correctly?

I've looked through other similar lp questions on here, but I don't see very many on free variables. But please link me to other questions if you think otherwise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lpSolve is somewhat of a pain to use. However, it should not be too difficult to implement a free variable using a technique called variable splitting. I.e. replace the free variable x by xplus-xmin with xplus,xmin>=0. Not both can be non-zero (then the basis matrix would be singular).

I think this is the correct updated code:

```
library(lpSolve)

DMU = c("FOR01", "FOR02", "FOR03", "FOR04", "FOR05")

log.data = matrix(data = as.numeric(c("1.794","1.575","3.576"
                                      ,"2.228","2.106","6.628"
                                      ,"2.399","1.871","6.354"
                                      ,"2.619","1.983","5.849"
                                      ,"2.559","1.541","5.676")), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

colnames(log.data) = c("M1", "M2", "M3")
rownames(log.data) = DMU

theta = c(-1,-1,-1,0)

add.to.one = c(1,1,1,1,1) # Constraint so each lambda adds up to one.

f.obj = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,-1)

f.con = cbind(rbind(t(log.data), add.to.one),theta,-theta)

f.dir = c("<=","<=","<=","=")

f.rhs = c(1.794,1.575,3.576,1)

r <- lp(direction = "min", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)
```

Better would be to use a more capable tool such as CVXR.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly, I even went ahead and tested it with the other forecasts and the results matched exactly. I'll make a note of CVXR and try using that in the future. Thanks!